# Is initializing for loops using braced initialization in C++11 considered bad form?

Tags: c++11, for-loop, initialization

The recommended way to initialize variables in C++11 is using braced initialization, but I almost never see this implemented in for loops:

```
// regular initialization
for(auto i = my_vector.size(); i > 0; --i){
  …
}

// brace-init-list initialization
for(auto i{my_vector.size()}; i > 0; --i){
  …
}
```

Is this considered bad form or is it not done for historical reasons?

Comment: Note that on first iteration `i` is the index of the one past the last one element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For standard C++11 and 14, your second example should actually not work, because the type of `i` will be deduced to `std::initializer_list<int>`.

This will be changed in C++17 so that the type is correctly deduced to `int`. The reason you can see the change already is that the `std::initializer_list` deduction in a direct initialization context is seen as a standards defect, so some compilers have already rectified this. Since you can't rely on whether or not a given compiler version has this change implemented, it's best not to use this initialization form for portable code.

Comment: Thanks. So, would it be correct if I just changed it to `for(size_t i{my_vector.size()}; i > 0; --i`?

Comment: @nachocab Yep, it's such an issue which effects `auto`.

Answer (score 1):

Brace-initialization was a bit flawed with `auto`, see [N3922](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html).

A correct portable way for a reverse loop:

```
for(auto i = my_vector.size(); i--;)
```

For forward loop:

```
for(auto j = my_vector.size(), i = 0; i < j; ++i)
```